# How to execute a function after a request has timed out?

Tags: ios, swift, timeout, nsurlsession, session-timeout

Currently I have a function that retrieves data from a server. There is a time out request on it for five seconds. I'm not completely sure if the timeout request is working because nothing happens after five seconds.  I'm trying to have it show an alert view to the user when the time out request finishes.  Here is the code:

```
 lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration =   URLSessionConfiguration.default

 lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

 typealias JSONData = ((Data) -> Void)

  func getJSONData(type: String, urlExtension: String, completion: @escaping JSONData) {

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"\(baseURL)\(type)/\(urlExtension)?api_key=\(apiKey)&region=US&append_to_response=videos,images,releases")! )

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

      if error == nil {
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            if let data = data {
              completion(data)
            }
          default:
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
      }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

Comment: Hi try replacing else part with 
else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(nil)
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")

            }
      }

Comment: any update, have you tried this ?

Comment: I'm trying it, maybe its the internet but when I put a break point in there it prints the error, but if I don't put a break point it just keeps going with no error printing

Comment: ok, so once internet is fine, can you update once, whatever the current state will be.